# Illustrator: trying to move path but instead it moves entire shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

Im trying to edit text in illustrator, I've created the outlines and. I'm using the direct select tool but whenever I try to move just a path or anchor point it moves the entire letter. Is there something I'm doing wrong to a way I can fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using the white arrow with no + sign?

Comment: You may simply be missing the *actual* anchor point or path. Illustrator can be *terribly* frustrating with it's target inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1):

With the white arrow selected, drag over the anchor point you want to move, it'll be selected  and you can then move that anchor point without changing the entire path.

Answer (score 1):

Listing the steps you should be doing, in case you are missing something:

- create the text
- with that selected, convert to outlines via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and your text is now converted to shapes
- hit <kbd>A</kbd> for direct selection tool
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to go into outline mode, this is optional, but will help you select lines instead of shapes. you can go out of outline mode by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> again
- use the mouse to click on any letter edge and you can select that line, you will also see some blue dots along the line, you can also click those separately to move points independently, or combine with holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select more than one point